# .Net web service client generates different proxy code in VS 2010 and VS2008

Tags: .net, wcf, ssis, webservice-client, workday-api

I am working on a Soap client for the [Workday Web Service API](https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/index.html).
There are code examples on the Workday Community site for .Net **3.5**. 
I got the code for 3.5 working in Visual Studio 2010 targeting .Net **3.5**. The *reference.cs* that is generated contains everything that the sample code expects.

However, I need to put the web service client into an SSIS script task for SQL Server 2008, which means the script project is generated for VS 2008. The latest .Net framework target version that is available there is also **3.5**. On the same development box that also has Visual Studio 2010 installed, and using the same WSDL, the generated proxy code is very different and does not work with my client code. Specifically, this part of the WSDL

```
<wsdl:portType name="Benefits_AdministrationPort">
 <wsdl:operation name="Put_Benefit_Annual_Rate">
  <wsdl:input name="Put_Benefit_Annual_RateInput" 
      message="wd-wsdl:Put_Benefit_Annual_Rate_RequestInputMsg" />
  <wsdl:output name="Put_Benefit_Annual_RateOutput" 
      message="wd-wsdl:Put_Benefit_Annual_Rate_ResponseOutputMsg" />
  <wsdl:fault name="Validation_Fault" 
      message="wd-wsdl:Validation_FaultMsg" />
  <wsdl:fault name="Processing_Fault" 
      message="wd-wsdl:Processing_FaultMsg" />
 </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

results in these proxy elements generated in VS2010:

```
public interface Benefits_AdministrationPort : ....

public partial class Benefits_AdministrationPortClient :     
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WorkDayWWSTestClient.WorkdayBenefits.
   Benefits_AdministrationPort>, WorkDayWWSTestClient.WorkdayBenefits.
   Benefits_AdministrationPort {
   ....
```

In my VS2008 project, these things are missing from *reference.cs*. Both projects reference the same version of the *System.ServiceModel* assembly (3.0.0.0).
The client code instantiates the Benefits_AdministrationPortClient class, so obviously not having the class is a problem.

I can take the proxy code that was generated in my VS 2010 project and drop it into the VS 2008 SSIS script task project, and everything works and my client can successfully update Workday. So I have a workaround, but when the web service is updated, the code gets overwritten, so this is not a good solution.

I don't understand what pieces are in play here - Service Model, .Net version, or Visual Studio, and how I can get VS 2008 to generate the correct code. Any ideas?

Comment: MS has made numerous changes to the proxy code generator between VS2005 and VS2012. There may be a legacy web service mode in VS2010 that can give you the results you are looking for.